# how to remove the excess space on the graph in python?

Tags: python

How do i get rid of the extra space on the graph due to the extreme values.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pywYT.png)

The code that i used is shown below:

```
plt.figure
sns.distplot(precip)
plt.title('Precipitation')
plt.xlabel('Precipitation (mm)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
plt.figure()
sns.distplot(precip)
plt.title('Precipitation')
plt.xlabel('Precipitation (mm)')
plt.xlim(0, upper_limit) # enter the value for the upper limit
plt.show()
```

plt.xlim sets a limit to the x axis
you can do something like `upper_limit = np.percentile(precip, 95)`
for the 95th %